# Force a static method with multiple same type of parameter arguments

Tags: java, generics

I need a generic static method to accept same type (class) of objects to compare them reflexively. (compile time check)

For example if the first argument is String; the second also to be String.

I thought below will work; but didn't. I can pass any two different objects to the below :(.

```
public static <T> void compareAndSetNonEditableFields(T current, T old){}
```

Even the below is not working. Pls help.

```
public static <T> void compareAndSetNonEditableFields(Class<T> type, T current, T old){}
```

**UPDATE_1**

---

Team Thanks for your help, But the solution given below `ClassName.<String>` is optional one, if i use it then only i will come to know i am setting some thing wrong; but most of the developer don't know this usage(i am also newly learned now only; Thanks); they may call this static API directly :(

**UPDATE_2**

---

Even if i go with non static way; i am not able to block sub class to be used instead of super class.
Like below. There is no compilation issue. And I don't know whether it is valid or not. Considering this, comparatively i will be following @Ingo answer for now.

```
public class HandlingNonEditableFields<T> {

    public void compareAndSetNonEditableFields(T currentObject, T oldObject) {
    }

    public  static void main(String[] args)  {
        SuperClass obj1 = new SuperClass();
        SubClass obj2   = new SubClass();
        new HandlingNonEditableFields<SuperClass>().
             compareAndSetNonEditableFields(obj1, obj2);
    }
 }
```

**UPDATE_3**

---

Non Static method way:

I tried to force it by adding `Class<T>` as one of my argument. But even this is also not worked.

```
    public void compareAndSetNonEditableFields(Class<T> type2ForceT, T currentObject, T oldObject) {       }
```

It throws exception to use `Class<? extends MainTestClass>` at method declarations. Else i have to cast explicitly at method callee.

**Conclusion**

---

At compile time; It is not possible to force same class level arguments to pass to a generic method declared as both Static and Non-Static .

Comment: "Even the below is not working." How does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
static <X, Y extends X> boolean method(X a, Y b)
```

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar  Note that the second argument could still be a subtype of the type of the first, though. So it is not exactly the "same type". But at least it catches cases liek String and Integer.

Comment: No matter what arguments are given, choosing `X = Object` and `Y = Object` is a valid choice that will allow it to be compiled. Just because your compiler doesn't infer it doesn't mean it solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call your method in the following way:

```
ClassName.<String>compareAndSetNonEditableFields("test", "test2"); // ok

ClassName.<String>compareAndSetNonEditableFields("test", 12); // compile time error
```

Comment: No; I dont know which object type i will get at the run time

Comment: I don't think you can use variables as type parameter, so it might not be possible to do it?

Comment: If i know String only i am passing i would directly used it; why it needs generics ??

Comment: yes, but unfortunately I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: @EdgarBoda Hi, Are you fine with ingo answer..?

Answer (score 0):

> I can pass any two different objects to the below :(.

That's right, and you should be able to. It's working correctly. `T` can be `Object`, and any reference type is a subtype of `Object`. Both arguments are indeed instances of the same type -- `Object`. You should just write it as

```
public static void compareAndSetNonEditableFields(Object current, Object old){}
```

Basically, what you want doesn't any make sense for Generics. Generics is not for making arbitrary restrictions; Generics is for *type safety*. It allows us to provide relationships between types so that we can prove that they support a certain operation without needing to explicitly cast. The type `T` has no bounds, which means you cannot rely on it to have any particular method or field, except those provided by `Object` to all reference type. This means you are not doing anything in that method that cares about the types of the objects (at least, in a type-safe way). Therefore, the method should be able to take any argument without problem.